# delete selected checkbox item after selection from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have popup on which there is a list of checkbox items to select. After selecting item from popup and clicking 'Update' button, value displays on the page.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="" id="popup_form">

           <div class="added">
           <div class="column-left">
             <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="One" id="checkbox1" data-toggle="checkbox">
         One
          </label>
          <br/>
          <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox2" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Two" id="checkbox2" data-toggle="checkbox">
           Two
          </label>
          <br/>

                  </div>

                   <div class="column-center">
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox3" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Three" id="checkbox3" data-toggle="checkbox">
   Three
          </label>
                 <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox4" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Four" id="checkbox4" data-toggle="checkbox">
          Four
          </label>
                 <br/>

          </div>

            <div class="column-center-right">
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox5" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Five" id="checkbox5" data-toggle="checkbox">
        Five
          </label> 
            <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox6" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Six" id="checkbox6" data-toggle="checkbox">
           Six
          </label> 
            <br/>

           </div>

            <div class="column-right">

           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox7" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value=" Seven" id="checkbox7" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Seven
          </label> 
             <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox8" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Eight" id="checkbox8" data-toggle="checkbox">
       Eight
          </label> 
             <br/>

          </div>

           </div> 
     <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="update" class="button button-orange" style="width: 90px; margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: -533px;" value="Update">
           <input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" class="button button-orange" style="width: 90px; background-color:#36606e;" value="Cancel">

</form>
```

Now I want that selected item should delete from the popup list. e.g. if value 'One' is selected then that should remove from that popup list items and should display on the page.

I did not get solution for it. How can I get that with jquery or javascript?

Any help will be helpful.

Popup list is something like below image[image]

After clicking 'Update' selected item will be displayed on page like below
[image]

Comment: @Noman I am not getting how to get that.

Comment: No php code and no jquery code. Share your code with us, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I don't have jquery/JS code. I am not getting it for above case.

Comment: you need to atleast add a `screen shot/picture` of this html, so someone can help you with jquery.

Comment: @noman I have added images for reference.

Comment: Check my answer again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

viewing selected item on another element

http://plnkr.co/edit/3lqVQfuqJ7ZTKMbIlGpH?p=preview

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.push-button').click(function() {
    $('input[name=complaint]:checked').parent().hide();
    var list = $('.content ul');
    list.empty();
    $('input[name=complaint]:checked').each(function() {
      var item = $('<li>');
      item.html($(this).val());
      list.append(item);
    });

  });
});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" data-semver="2.1.4" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="added">
           <div class="column-left">
             <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="One" id="checkbox1" data-toggle="checkbox">
         One
          </label>
          <br/>
          <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox2" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Two" id="checkbox2" data-toggle="checkbox">
           Two
          </label>
          <br/>

                  </div>

                   <div class="column-center">
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox3" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Three" id="checkbox3" data-toggle="checkbox">
   Three
          </label>
                 <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox4" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Four" id="checkbox4" data-toggle="checkbox">
          Four
          </label>
                 <br/>

          </div>

            <div class="column-center-right">
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox5" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Five" id="checkbox5" data-toggle="checkbox">
        Five
          </label> 
            <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox6" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Six" id="checkbox6" data-toggle="checkbox">
           Six
          </label> 
            <br/>

           </div>

            <div class="column-right">

           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox7" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value=" Seven" id="checkbox7" data-toggle="checkbox">
            Seven
          </label> 
             <br/>
           <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox8" style="font-size:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="Eight" id="checkbox8" data-toggle="checkbox">
       Eight
          </label> 
             <br/>

          </div>

           </div> 

<button type="button" class="push-button">List Data To the Content </button>


<div class="content">
  <h1>View Selected Datas</h1>
  <ul class="content-list">

  </ul>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. In the link you provided, when we select e.g. 'One', other items removed. That I does not look for. I want the selected item should remove from list when we click on button and also it should display on page. This is happening opposite which I was expecting.

Comment: I am using item 'One' for example. your demo is working for item 'One' only. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: yes. the Selected item should remove from list and should display on page when we click on the Button. In my case I am using list on popup. When I click on 'Update' button that selected item should remove and should display on page. If next time I click on '+Add/Edit' button then that item should not be in that list.

Comment: The selected item is removing as soon as we check on checkbox. Can it be removed after we click on button?

Comment: Great..Thanks a lot Saltuk. That's what I was expecting. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101864/discussion-between-saltuk-and-kiran).